# Select all user that have a specific date and have been recorded only one time

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this table.

[My Sql table in (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a9ce/5/0)

```
ID       Date       Value 
___      ____       _____
3241     01/01/00   15456
3241     9/17/12    5
3241     9/16/12    100
3241     9/15/12    20
4355     01/01/00   01
4355     9/16/12    12
4355     9/15/12    132
4355     9/14/12    4
1001     01/01/00   456
1001     9/16/12    125
5555     01/01/00   01
1234     01/01/00   01
1234     9/16/12    45
2236     01/01/00   879
2236     9/15/12    128
2236     9/14/12    323
2002     01/01/00   567
```

I would like, to `select` all the record that have `01-01-00 as date` and have been showed only one time.
The result that i'm trying to have is like the table below.

```
ID       Date       Value 
___      ____       _____
5555     01/01/00   01
2002     01/01/00   567
```

I tried to use `HAVING` clause but because of the `GROUP BY`, the result is ***wrong*** because one of my select has more than one record which isn't good for my case.

My Wrong Attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id, date, value
   HAVING count(Id)=1) t1
WHERE date='01-01-00'
```

[Query Result (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a9ce/5/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
select id, max(date) as date, max(value) as value
from t1
group by id
having max(date) = '01-01-00' and count(*) = 1;
```

A somewhat faster method might be:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where date = '01-01-00' and
      not exists (select 1 from t1 tt1 where tt1.id = t1.id and tt1.date <> '01-01-00');
```

This can take advantage of index on `t1(date)` and `t1(id, date)`.

Comment: Query #1 will fail in Teradata (and any other DBMS besides MySQL) with *3504 Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group*.  You need to add `MAX` to both `date` and `value`. And #2 might return multiple rows with the same `id` & `'01-01-00'` combination, but different `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id
     FROM table1
     GROUP BY id
     HAVING count(Id)=1
   ) and date='01-01-00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING count(id)=1) t1
WHERE t1.date='01-01-00'
```

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is an anti-pattern -- bad SQL (and it will fail in Teradata).

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't notice that i make a error in my `group by` instead of making only the `ID`, I put all the `columns`

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY `ID`
   HAVING count(`ID`)=1) t1
WHERE `Date`='2000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

However for my problem, I take [this solution from Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46157291/2954082) because it's seems better for me.

PS:I have 2 million  records.